# Shift Column based on Values in other column in pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe, conditional-statements, shift

I have a `dataframe` like follows:

```
id  FY   SY   TY   Ylen
1   2018 2019 nan  2
2   2017 2018 2019 3
3   2018 2019 2020 3
4   2019 nan  nan  1
5   2018 nan  nan  1
```

I want to shift the column based on the number present in `Ylen`, such that it looks like this:

```
id  FY   SY   TY   Ylen
1   nan  2018 2019 2
2   2017 2018 2019 3
3   2018 2019 2020 3
4   nan  nan  2019 1
5   nan  nan  2018 1
```

is it possible to `shift()` with condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First is necessary same types of data, here `float`s and then [`DataFrame.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) columns by condition:

```
c = ['FY','SY','TY']

df[c] = df[c].astype(float)

for s in df['Ylen'].unique():
    m = df['Ylen'].eq(s)
    df.loc[m, c] = df.loc[m, c].shift(len(c)-s, axis=1)
print (df)
   id      FY      SY      TY  Ylen
0   1     NaN  2018.0  2019.0     2
1   2  2017.0  2018.0  2019.0     3
2   3  2018.0  2019.0  2020.0     3
3   4     NaN     NaN  2019.0     1
4   5     NaN     NaN  2018.0     1
```

Comment: That's Awesome. Thanks.